# ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream memory consumption

Tags: java, spring

Good afternoon, I want to know about a possible memory leak in this place. I create a temporary file and write data there, about 10 million lines. At the same time, there is a large consumption of memory (RAM). Is that the problem? How can I reduce its consumption (at least 2 times) when writing to a file if this is the problem?

I also use ObjectInputStream to read this file. Maybe you can find something to deal with it as well?

There is not much RAM, maximum 6 GB

```
public class Test {
private File file;
private ObjectOutputStream out;

public Test() {
    try {
        this.file = File.createTempFile(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), ".tmp");
        this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}

private void writeToDisk() {
    try {
        for (Iterator<E> it = super.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            out.writeObject(it.next());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
}
```

DATA:

```
public class myDTO implements Serializable {
private int number;
private String title;
private String date;
private String city;
private String department;
private String userLogin;
private String userName;
private String userFam;
private String userFatherName;

....
}
```

Everything that has anything to do with serialization, so I prescribed implements Serializable

Comment: Maybe the garbage collector has not yet recovered the memory? You should use a profiler to find out how much is really allocated.

Comment: What data are you serializing? Do you know how Java serialization works and how it caches objects?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer I'm not sure about that, because everything happens for about 30 minutes

Comment: You can't be running the posted code because it doesn't compile; there is no E, and super.iterator() doesn't exist when superclass is to Object. **Please post code that actually has the problem**, which usually only happens if it is based on or similar to code you are actually using.